# error CS0266 no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List en System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-core

Eestoy trabajando en una  aplicacion  de  .Net Core 3 con angular  que registre empleados y visitantes. Me registra el error error:

> CS0266 no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List en
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

solo me  aparece en la clase  de visitantes  y no  en la de  empleados

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext    
{

public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options) : base(options)

{ }
public DbSet<Empleados> Empleados { get; set; }

public DbSet<Visitantes> Visitantes { get; set; }

 }


public class Empleados    
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public int Documento { get; set; }

public string Nombres { get; set; }

public string Apellidos { get; set; }

public string Cargo { get; set; }

public string Ciudad { get; set; }    
}

public class Visitante    
{        
public int Id { get; set; }

public int Documento { get; set; }

public string Nombres { get; set; }

public string Apellidos { get; set; }

public string Cargo { get; set; }

public string Ciudad { get; set; }    
}
```

en la  clase  empleados no me registra el error

```
public IEnumerable<ViewEmpleados> Empleados()        
{            

  List<ViewVisitantes> lst = (from d in db.Visitantes

  select new ViewVisitantes {
     Id = d.Id,                                           
     Documento = d.Documento,                                           
     Nombre = d.Nombres,                                           
     Apellido = d.Apellidos,                                           
     Cargo = d.Cargo,
     Ciudad = d.Ciudad,                                      
   }).ToList();

  return lst; el error registra  en esta parte 
}
```

Comment: El método `Empleados()` devuelve un `IEnumerable<ViewEmpleados>`, y tu le estás devolviendo un `List<ViewVisitantes>` ??. Las listas debes tener el mismo tipo de objeto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cambia la función 
"public IEnumerable Empleados()" por: 
"public list< ViewVisitantes > Empleados()"

Un saludo

Edit:

Un par de observaciones:

1. Creo que hay una confusión con los nombres, la función la llamas Empleados() pero estás devolviendo un view model de Visitantes.
2. Yo no construiría el view model desde una consulta a bbdd porque tendrás que repetirla nuevamente si mas adelante necesitas consultar únicamente Empleados. Considero que es mejor tener la consulta en un método y luego usar otro para transformar esa lista en un view model, eso te dará mas escalabilidad y podrás reutilizar más código.